# Return Value on the Stack in x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, x86-64

For an assignment I had to create a function in x86 ASM, which should calculate the determinante of a matrix and return its result over the stack to the main function.

My question is now how can I push the result to the stack.

I know the standard for return values is the register %rax, but the assignment stated to use the stack.

So in the main it looks something like this:

```
    pushq a
    pushq b
    pushq c
    pushq d
    call determinante
    popq %r12
```

wheras a, b, c, d are the values for the matrix and determinante should now push the result in the stackframe of main and with popq %r12, we want to write it to the register r12.

Not literally push it to the stack but the Assignment said:

```
determinant: # returns the result in the last parameter in stack
```

Just a small tip on how to push a value to the stack in a function would help a lot.

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: Are you sure you're not supposed to have the function take a pointer arg on the stack, and store the result to memory pointed-to by that arg?  If you really need to return with something on the stack, the question becomes "where".  You can't just `push` it, because then `ret` will pop it (instead of the return address) into RIP.  You could overwrite a stack arg above the return address, or you could manually remove or copy the return address.  (Then `push reg`/ `ret` to actually return)

Comment: Here's [an example](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/symsnip/file/bffa9d8c4571/binsrch.asm#l735) of a function that returns something on the stack. In this case the caller needs to push a placeholder parameter so that the parameters take up enough space to hold the return value. In your question you have 4 qword parameters already so you can simply store your result to the space occupied by the highest-addressed parameter (corresponding to `pushq a`). Then return with `retn 24` (= 3 * 8) to free up the space occupied by the three other parameters.

Comment: Thanks ecm, I knew I have to have a placeholder and I know I have such placeholder but my Question was more regarding the how I can store the result to this space.

And I couldn't find this out with your example, I'm not very profound with ASM x86 so this example was a bit to complicated.

Comment: like `mov %rax, 8(%rsp)` right before you would `ret`, if you have your return value in RAX.  Unlike the 16-bit code ecm linked, x86-64 allows you to reference memory relative to the stack pointer itself.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I tried this, but it wouldn't work but now it does, so thanks.

Comment: You don't want to actually reach into the stack after returning from a function. The space that was just "freed" should be considered for all intents and purposes "gone" (because one IRQ hit later and it probably will be.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example in 16bits mode, to explain the concept :

```
xor ax, ax
push ax       ; we'll gonna use this to return a value in the function
call my_func

pop ax        ; the returned value is at top of the stack (actually at the
              ; bottom of the stack because the stack grow down)
;...


my_func:
  pusha
  mov bp, sp
  
  ;... do something here ..
  
  mov [bp + 18], ax ; we are returning the value of ax
                    ; 18 because pusha pushes 8 registers + IP register pushed
                    ; pushed by default when calling a function
                    ; so the offset = 8*2 + 1*2
  popa
  ret

;.....
```

Comment: You can check my project here : [MROS](https://github.com/KHBillel/MROS) , it can be useful

Comment: 64-bit mode doesn't have `pusha` so this doesn't port directly.  Also, if you're going to set up BP / RBP as a frame pointer at all, normally you'd point it at the stack slot right below the return address (after one `push bp`).

Comment: "pusha" means push all general purpose register. So if it does not exist, you can push them one by one depending on which registers you want to preserve. For "push bp" , it is included in "pusha".

Comment: so yeah, in 64-bit mode, you need to `push` the registers one by one, and `pop` them in the inverse order. Also, you're right, `rbp` need to be preserved before modifying it, it did not do that because it's already done by `pusha`

Comment: Or since this is x86-64, you don't need to do any of that.  `mov [rsp+8], rax` right before `ret`.  32 and 64-bit addressing modes can use the stack pointer directly.  Also, you wouldn't want to push/pop all 15 registers (other than RSP), so that's not a good suggestion for a 64-bit version of this. You *could*, but that's very inefficient.  And like I said, if you are going to set up RBP to point into your stack frame at all, the traditional stack-frame layout has RBP pointing at the saved RBP right below the return address, not to the bottom of the space where you pushed multiple regs.

Comment: If you do want to save multiple call-preserved registers, you'd push others after the initial `push rbp` / `mov rbp, rsp`, like compilers do.  https://godbolt.org/z/T6cGrPdbs .  Since `pusha` doesn't exist, there's no benefit to doing something else that points RBP somewhere else.